# Magento category view next and previous page toolbar

Tags: magento

Whomever worked on the site previous me has somehow turned off the toolbar on the category view page. They had wanted to get rid of the filter by, and other options.

Now we have too many products to display them all on one page, so I went ahead and limited it to show 12 products, which it does. But now navigation shows up. I assume this is because of how they turned off the toolbar. Where do I find the code (using a theme) to control this toolbar? I am hoping they just commented out the code.

Magento 1.9.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is also a possibility to remove toolbar in layout xml.

most common place for this would be local.xml of the Theme
app/design/frontend/[theme]/layout/local.xml

can also be done in any other xml (like catalog.xml) in
app/design/frontend/[theme]/layout/

simply search for `product_list_toolbar` block and actions like `remove` or `unsetChild`

Comment: `//Hide toolbar
    $hideToolbar = false;
    if ($this->getHideToolbar())
    {
        $hideToolbar = true;
    }`
I see this code in my theme list.phtml, is this hiding the toolbar?

Comment: it looks like someone implemented a method getHideToolbar and perhaps a system configuration value. check where getHideToolbar is defined and post method body for code review

Comment: `   //Hide toolbar
    $hideToolbar = false;
    if ($this->getHideToolbar())
    {
        $hideToolbar = true;
    }
?>

<div class="category-products">
    <?php if (!$hideToolbar): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): //List mode ?>

    <?php
        //Get list configuration array
        $lc = $theme->getCfgGroup('category_list');
        
        //List classes
        $listClasses = '';
        if ($lc['hover_effect'])
            $listClasses = ' hover-effect';
    ?>`

Comment: getHideToolbar is only found on two pages, both in my theme one the basic theme, one in the theme for our site, like a modification theme. on the catalog/product/list.phtml
Identical code on each one

Comment: Turns out they wrote a css code to not display the toolbar. nothing in the actual page codes.

Answer (score 0):

**over ride the below given files  into your theme**

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml

and you can see the code that call child html of tool bar 
in line numbers 42 and 125 for bottom side

*`<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>`*

so if you commented this line then corresponding tool bars not shows

or if you want to customize the tool bar part then you can edit in the file.

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml

**this file is render for toolbar**